# Вчера бывает сегодня?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

[Вопрос](//rus.stackexchange.com/q/454296/185185) задан сутки назад, дата (как местная, так и по UTC) уже давно поменялась, но отображается, что он задан "сегодня":

> [image: Скриншот с "сегодня"]

А вот когда сутки прошли, стало "вчера":

> [image: Скриншот со "вчера"]

Это некорректный перевод?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы с переводом все в порядке, я проверил. Также посмотрел на новые вопросы за вчерашний и сегодняшний дни — с ними тоже ничего странного.

Видимо, на данный момент баг не воспроизводится.

Спасибо за сообщение!